# How to correctly handle dates in queries constraints

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I am currently using the following query to get all the inspections done on june 2010:

```
select inspections.name
from inspections
where
  to_char(inspections.insp_date, 'YYYY') = 2010 and
  to_char(inspections.insp_date, 'MM') = 06;
```

but this feels kinda awkward. Wouldn't there be a better way of doing this? Looking at http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html it doesn't seem so. I am using Oracle, if it makes a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I like to use range comparison when possible since this can be used for index-scan by the optimizer:

```
select inspections.name
  from inspections
 where inspections.date >= DATE '2010-06-01'
   and inspections.date < DATE '2010-07-01'
```

Comment: hmmmm, in turn, i think it is less clear than the original query :(

Comment: @devoured elysium : this would be subjective I guess, while the ability to use an index is not :)

Comment: I think it is more clear that the original qery and writing SQL that will never use the indexes when there is a perfectly good way of doing that will use the indexes, it is a poor idea. Anyone writing SQL needs to understand what is sargable and what is not. Clarity (which is subjective by programmer) does NOT trump performance in database querying.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Vincent's answer, but for completeness you could simplify yours to:

```
select inspections.name
from inspections
where
  to_char(inspections.insp_date, 'YYYYMM') = '201006';
```

That could even use an index, provided the index were:

```
create index x on inspections (to_char(insp_date, 'YYYYMM'));
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what is going on with 201006 :(

Comment: @devoured: really? well you could use 'YYYY-MM' and '2010-06' instead.

Comment: Jeffrey you are not taking this seriously!!

Answer (score 3):

```
select inspections.name
from inspections
where
  extract(year from inspections.insp_date) = 2010 and
  extract(month from inspections.insp_date) = 6;
```

Comment: looks nice. but it seems like a subquery, of some sort. is it any efficient? thanks!

Comment: there's no subquery, just oracle-specific syntax for simple function.

Comment: EXTRACT() isn't specific to Oracle; it's standard SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be

```
SELECT inspections.name
  FROM inspections
 WHERE TRUNC( inspections.insp_date, 'MM' ) = date '2010-06-01';
```

From an efficiency perspective

- Vincent's solution can potentially use a range scan on an index on INSP_DATE (assuming that the table has many months of data such that index access would be the most efficient plan).
- My query can potentially use a function-based index on TRUNC( insp_date, 'MM' ) again assuming that the table has many months of data.  If there is a large variation in the number of rows for different months, the optimizer's cardinality estimates may be slightly more accurate with this function-based index than they would be on a straight INSP_DATE index but that is highly unlikely to be important in a query this simple.  It could come into play, however, if you start nesting this query elsewhere.  If you need to index INSP_DATE for other reasons, however, maintaining two different indexes is potentially a time and space waster.
- Your initial query and Lev's query could both potentially use a composite function-based index (though you'd want to include an explicit TO_NUMBER or compare to strings rather than numbers to avoid implicit conversions).  The composite index, though, is likely to be the least efficient to maintain (though we're talking here about relatively small differences) and strikes me as the least clean of the index alternatives.

Comment: It's hard to predict index efficiency without full list of typical queries.