# How to extract only date value from date field in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle database.I dont have much knowledge about date-time concepts in Oracle.
The problem i am facing is to retrieve records which are entered on a particular date.But when i am executing SQL query on database it returns zero records.

Database has date field which contains records with both datetime value.

SQL Query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.daterecord = to_date(03-Mar-2010)`

It is not returning any record but if i change my query to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.daterecord > to_date(04-Mar-2010)
```

It will return some records.
The above difference is because of time.How can i extract time value from date. Can I use trunc function for this? Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can use TRUNC function.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE TRUNC(table.daterecord) = TO_DATE('03-Mar-2010', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
```

Answer (score 8):

see this SO for suggestions of "[How to correctly handle dates in queries constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876771/how-to-correctly-handle-dates-in-queries-constraints)"?

In addition to the answers already provided, I would suggest using a range since this is more easily indexable:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE table.daterecord >= TO_DATE('03-Mar-2010', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
   AND table.daterecord < TO_DATE('04-Mar-2010', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
```

Comment: +1, I like this due to ability to use index (vs trunc)

Comment: +1 for your answer in the other question :)

Comment: Given that you know this is a duplicate question you should have voted to close the question, rather than duplicating your answer.  It's not like you really need the points.

Comment: @APC: I felt that the questions were sufficiently distinct. My answer is a duplicate though (same principle applied to another case), maybe I should have pointed to the question in a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [TRUNC](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)

For example :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE TRUNC(table.daterecord) = TO_DATE('03-Mar-2010', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
```