# How to select all data from table but only display date-specific rows within DATE-data type column, in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm experiencing trouble returning a query to return all columns within a table but limited to the DATE-data-type "enroll_date" column containing '30-Jan-07'; the closest solution is with the below query but neither data is displayed nor the entire workbook-just the column-which leads me to believe that this is not just an issue with approach but perhaps a formatting issue as well.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(enroll_date, 'DD-MM-YY')
FROM student.enrollment
WHERE enroll_date= '30-Jan-07';
```

Again, I need to display all columns but only rows only specific to the date '30-Jan-07'.  I'm sure a nested solution is ideal and somehow the right solution, but unfortunately my chops aren't there yet but I'm working on it! :D

### UPDATE

Please see attached screenshot of output.  The query/solution should retrieve all columns and rows enclosed within the red-rectangle mark-up-thank you!

[image]

Comment: Use [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) string with the proper formatter.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract only date value from date field in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542080/how-to-extract-only-date-value-from-date-field-in-oracle)

Comment: If you are using SQL Developer then go to `Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS` and update the `Date Format` to something like `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` to display the time component. If you are in SQL/Plus then you can do `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`. This will show you why your dates are not being matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem is that the date column has a time component (this is hidden in SQL).  One method is to use `trunc()`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM student.enrollment e
WHERE TRUNC(e.enroll_date) = DATE '2007-01-30';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify whichever columns you want in the following query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM student.enrollment
WHERE TO_CHAR(enroll_date, 'DD-MON-YY') = '30-JAN-07';
```

Comment: Please make sure your are replacing the col list with actual column names and that you are not putting an extra comma in the end

Comment: And its TO_CHAR instead of TO_DATE, sorry it was my falut