# Equals(=) vs. LIKE for date data type

Tags: sql, oracle

First, I am aware that this question has been posted generally [Equals(=) vs. LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like).
Here, I query about date type data on ORACLE database, I found the following, when I write select statment in this way:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE LIKE '30-JUL-07';
```

I get all rows I'm looking for. but when I use the sign equal `=` instead :

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = '30-JUL-07';
```

I get nothing even though nothing is different except the equal sign. Can I find any explanation for this please ?

Comment: I guess the first one only matches `30-Jul-07 00:00:00` whereas the second matches `30-Jul-07 **:**:**` ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming `LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE` is a `DATE` column (or `TIMESTAMP`) then both version are very bad practice.

In both cases the `DATE` column will implicitly be converted to a character literal based on the current NLS settings. That means with different clients you will get different results.

When using date literals ***always*** use `to_date()` with(!) a format mask or use an ANSI date literal. That way you compare dates with dates not strings with strings. So for the equal comparison you should use:

```
LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = to_date('30-JUL-07', 'dd-mon-yy')
```

Note that using 'MON' can still lead to errors with different NLS settings (`'DEC'` vs. `'DEZ'` or `'MAR'` vs. `'MRZ'`). It is much less error prone using month numbers (and four digit years):

```
LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = to_date('30-07-2007', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

or using an ANSI date literal

```
LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = DATE '2007-07-30'
```

Now the reason why the above query is very likely to return nothing is that in Oracle `DATE` columns include the time as well. The above date literals implicitly contain  the time `00:00`. If the time in the table is different (e.g. `19:54`)  then of course the dates are not equal.

To workaround this problem you have different options:

1. use `trunc()` on the table column to "normalize" the time to `00:00` 
   `trunc(LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE) = DATE '2007-07-30`
   this will however prevent the usage of an index defined on `LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE`
2. use `between` 
   `LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE between to_date('2007-07-30 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2007-07-30 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`

The performance problem of the first solution could be worked around by creating an index on `trunc(LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE)` which could be used by that expression. But the expression `LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = '30-JUL-07'` prevents an index usage as well because internally it's processed as `to_char(LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE) = '30-JUL-07'`

The important things to remember:

1. Never, ever rely on implicit data type conversion. It *will* give you problems at some point. Always compare the correct data types
2. Oracle `DATE` columns always contain a time which is part of the comparison rules.

Comment: there is one extra 'y' on LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = to_date('30-07-2007', 'dd-mm-yyyyy'), please edit. I can't edit by myself since I need to edit at least 6 characters :) thanks

Comment: I think `between` also doesn't benefit from indexing.

Comment: I needed to use `LIKE` vs `=`, even with `to-date`, as in, `UPDATED_AT LIKE to_date('19-DEC-21', 'dd-mon-yy')`.

Answer (score 8):

You should not compare a date to a string directly. You rely on [implicit conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i53062), the rules of which are difficult to remember.

Furthermore, your choice of date format is not optimal: years have four digits (Y2K bug?), and not all languages have the seventh month of the year named `JUL`. You should use something like `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Finally, dates in Oracle are points in time precise to the second. **All dates have a time component**, even if it is `00:00:00`. When you use the `=` operator, Oracle will compare the date and time for dates.

Here's a test case reproducing the behaviour you described:

```
SQL> create table test_date (d date);

Table created

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';

Session altered

SQL> insert into test_date values
  2     (to_date ('2007/07/30 11:50:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from test_date where d = '30-JUL-07';

D
-----------

SQL> select * from test_date where d like '30-JUL-07';

D
-----------
30/07/2007
```

When you use the `=` operator, Oracle will convert the constant string `30-JUL-07` to a date and compare the value with the column, like this:

```
SQL> select * from test_date where d = to_date('30-JUL-07', 'DD-MON-RR');

D
-----------
```

When you use the `LIKE` operator, Oracle will convert the column to a string and compare it to the right-hand side, which is equivalent to:

```
SQL> select * from test_date where to_char(d, 'DD-MON-RR') like '30-JUL-07';

D
-----------
30/07/2007
```

Always compare dates to dates and strings to strings. Related question:

- [How to correctly handle dates in queries constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4876771/119634)

Comment: Assuming these data formats ain't under my control and I need to compare with the date 30-JUL-07 , I guess I have to use explicit conversion like this to_date('30-JUL-07'). right?

Comment: You have to use `to_date` with two arguments (the constant **and** the format :). Also `LIKE` is strictly a string operator and as such won't work well with dates.

Answer (score 1):

The date field is not a string.  Internally an implicit conversion is made to a string when you use `=`, which does not match anything because your string does not have the required amount of precision.

I'd have a guess that the `LIKE` statement behaves somewhat differently with a date field, causing implicit wildcards to be used in the comparison that eliminates the requirement for any precision.  Essentially, your `LIKE` works like this:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN DATE('30-JUL-07 00:00:00.00000+00:00') AND DATE('30-JUL-07 23:59:59.99999+00:00');
```