# Django Raw SQL query does not return todays records

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was making a appointment system using Django! I wanted to display todays appointments. This raw query must be returning today's records but it isn't returning any record!

**Query looks like this:**

```
todays_appointments = Appointment.objects.raw("""
    SELECT appointment_Appointment.id,
           loginReg_User.user_name,
           appointment_Appointment.task,
           appointment_Appointment.date,
           appointment_Appointment.time,
           appointment_Appointment.status
    FROM appointment_Appointment
    LEFT JOIN loginReg_User
    ON appointment_Appointment.user_id = loginReg_User.id
    WHERE loginReg_User.id={}
      AND appointment_Appointment.date={}
 ORDER BY appointment_Appointment.time".format(user_id, today"""))
```

Also, `today` looks something like this:

`today = datetime.date.today()`.

I tried running similar query in the shell using `Appointment.objects.filter(date=today)` and it worked fine!

**Models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from ..loginReg.models import User
from django.db import models
import datetime

class AppointmentValidator(models.Manager):
    def task_validator(self, task):
        if len(task) < 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def date_validator(self, date_time):
    present = datetime.now().date()
    if date_time < present:
        return False
    else:
        return True
def status(self, status):
    if status == "missed" or status == "done" or status == "pending":
        return True
    else:
        return False


class Queries(models.Manager):
    def todays_appointments(self, user_id):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        todays_appointments = Appointment.objects.raw("SELECT appointment_Appointment.id, loginReg_User.user_name, appointment_Appointment.task, appointment_Appointment.date, appointment_Appointment.time, appointment_Appointment.status FROM appointment_Appointment LEFT JOIN loginReg_User ON appointment_Appointment.user_id = loginReg_User.id WHERE loginReg_User.id={} AND appointment_Appointment.date={} ORDER BY appointment_Appointment.time".format(user_id, today))
    return todays_appointments

def other_appointments(self, user_id):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    other_appointments = `Appointment.objects.raw("SELECT            appointment_Appointment.id, loginReg_User.user_name, appointment_Appointment.task, appointment_Appointment.date, appointment_Appointment.time, appointment_Appointment.status FROM appointment_Appointment LEFT JOIN loginReg_User ON appointment_Appointment.user_id = loginReg_User.id WHERE loginReg_User.id={} AND appointment_Appointment.date>{} ORDER BY appointment_Appointment.time".format(user_id, today))`
    return other_appointments


class Appointment(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    time = models.TimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    appointmentManager = AppointmentValidator()
    queries = Queries()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: Don't use. `.format()` on any SQL query. It makes vulnerable to SQL injections. Use `%s` in the string and hand in the arguments as a list. Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: And in addition: what you are doing there can be done easily with the ORM.

Comment: any suggestions on how to do this using ORM? I'm new to django and this is like my first full blown project! Appreciate it!

Comment: Something like `Appointment.objects.filter(date=today(), user=user).order_by('time')`

Comment: Thank you, it works! That just cleared a clog in my thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Date is a DateField so you need to compare it to a date, not the formatted representation of the date (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505739/5679413). By using format, you are converting today into numbers and dashes. You're SQL query needs to turn it back into a date. Django presumably takes care of this for you.

Comment: if that was the case, then the second query `other_appointments` shouldn't be working for me! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Does it work? I get `operator does not exist: date > integer`

Comment: No the suggested post didn't help! But the other query with `>` works for me. Not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: What SQL flavour are you using? I'm getting the error in PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm using sqlite for now! Once things work will move it over to MySQL!

Comment: Interesting. I have to use `"SELECT * FROM appointment_Appointment WHERE appointment_Appointment.date>{}<to_date('{}', 'yyyy-mm-dd')".format(datetime.date.today())` to not get an error. I would suggest removing parts of your query until you get appointments for the current day to show up to make sure the problem isn't with something else.

Comment: got it! I will be playing around with it! I got it to work the right way using the ORM but wanted to try raw queries!

Comment: Yeah, I still use raw queries to quickly make downloadable csv's, so it isn't a completely useless skill.