# Output of the query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

### Query 1 :

```
select count(*) from CI_TXN_HEADER where TXN_HEADER_DTTM = '25-JAN-13';
```

Result: ***1***

### Query 2 :

```
select count(*) from CI_TXN_HEADER where TXN_HEADER_DTTM like '25-JAN-13';
```

Result: ***19***

In my DB I have 19 rows with `TXN_HEADER_DTTM` as *25-JAN-13*.
Data Type of `TXN_HEADER_DTTM` is `DATE`.

Can someone please explain the difference in output?

Comment: How many rows *should* match in the database?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ There are 19 rows with the given date in database, so the output should be same in both cases right? It should match 19 rows i suppose.

Comment: Can you run this query and post the output.? -  `select count(*), TXN_HEADER_DTTM FROM CI_TXN_HEADER GROUP BY TXN_HEADER_DTTM;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Oracle `DATE` column contains a date **and** a time. The `LIKE` condition is only for `VARCHAR` columns. If applied to other data types Oracle implicitly converts that to a varchar (using rules depending on the current client settings).

So you might have rows with e.g. `2013-01-25 17:42:01`, however the string constant `'25-JAN-13'` is (most probably) converted to: `2013-01-25 00:00:00` and thus the `=` comparison doesn't work.

To find all rows for a specific day use `trunc()` and a *proper* [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062). Don't rely on the evil implicit data type conversion to specify date values.

Use `trunc()` to set the time part of a `DATE` value to `00:00:00`:

I prefer ANSI SQL date literals:

```
select count(*) 
from CI_TXN_HEADER 
where trunc(TXN_HEADER_DTTM) = DATE '2013-01-25';
```

You can also use Oracle's to_date:

```
select count(*) 
from CI_TXN_HEADER 
where trunc(TXN_HEADER_DTTM) = to_date('2013-01-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Note that Oracle can't use an index on `TXN_HEADER_DTT`, so if performance is critical use a range query:

```
select count(*) 
from CI_TXN_HEADER 
where TXN_HEADER_DTTM >= DATE '2013-01-25'
  and TXN_HEADER_DTTM < DATE '2013-01-25' + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between like and equal is explained in this link very good
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336940/4506285

I checked your problem on my table and I get the same results.

This link helps also to understand how to compare dates in sql
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505739/4506285

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your data consists of space, it is not exactly '25-JAN-13' but ' 25-JAN-13';

Please refer this two link:

1. [Equals(=) vs. LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)
2. [What's the difference between "LIKE" and "=" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504990/whats-the-difference-between-like-and-in-sql)